# converting css linear gradient to react-native-linear-gradient

Tags: css, react-native, linear-gradients

I have a CSS gradient in Figma

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #0097F3 26.66%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
```

How can I convert that to [react-native-linear-gradient package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient/v/2.5.1)

I am doing the below code, I dont know how to do 180deg and 26 %  etc

```
<LinearGradient 
  start={{x: 0.26, y: 0.26}} 
        end={{x: 0, y: 1.0}}
        location={[0.25, 0.4]}
        colors={['#0097F3', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)']}
 style={{flex: 1}}
 >
........
</LinearGradient>
```

A value of 0deg is equivalent to "to top". A value of 90deg is equivalent to "to right". A value of 180deg is equivalent to "to bottom".

background-image: linear-gradient(angle, color-stop1, color-stop2);

1. start: An optional object of the following type: { x: number, y: number }. Coordinates declare the position that the gradient starts at, as a fraction of the overall size of the gradient, starting from the top left corner. Example: { x: 0.1, y: 0.1 } means that the gradient will start 10% from the top and 10% from the left.
2. end: Same as the start, but for the end of the gradient.
3. locations: An optional array of numbers defining the location of each gradient color stop, mapping to the color with the same index in colors prop. Example: [0.1, 0.75, 1] means that first color will take 0% – 10%, second color will take 10% – 75% and finally third color will occupy 75% – 100%.

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient#useangle--angle--anglecenter

Comment: Please don't add answers to your questions. I have rolled back/edited your question. Please write a new answer instead.